# How does the personalised/collaborative mode in zeppelin work?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

We have multiple users trying to run a single paragraph at the same time, using the personalized mode in zeppelin. But when one user runs the paragraph, the other user starts seeing the progress bar without running the paragraph himself and/or his paragraph hangs up. According to the JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1594
personalised mode does not support running the same paragraph simultaneously by multiple users. Has this been fixed in later version?

I am referring to the mode that can changed on the top of the notebook, not the binding modes of the interpreter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has this been fixed in later version?

Nope.
There are few bugs in personalized mode.
For example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3065